# Structured Support Vector Machine (Joint Feature Map)

Tags: feature-selection, svm

I'm studying Structured Support Vector Machine. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_support_vector_machine)

The theory's clear, but I need a tangible example to make everything more concrete.

Could you provide me with a real example of SSVM, specifying me the structured output space and the joint feature map Ψ(x,y)?

Happy Holidays